# magento language pack installation doesn't work

Tags: magento2, language-package

I am trying to install the language pack for magento 2.3.1, these are steps:

```
wget https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-italian-language-pack/raw/master/it_IT.csv
php bin/magento i18n:pack -m replace it_IT.csv it_IT
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f it_IT
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I am in developer mode so I need -f to deploy.
The i18n directory is not created, nothing happens.

I tried manually to insert the directories but it still doesn't work, language is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this below method will help you
Install italian language pack in magento 2.
Install the Italian language pack via command line. Download language file to your installation root directory. Now run the following command:

```
wget https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-italian-language-pack/raw/master/it_IT.csv
php bin/magento i18n:pack -m replace it_IT.csv it_IT
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy it_IT
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Create store view
Set theme for store view

you can follow below link
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-italian-language-pack.html